# App can't find plugin file

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to load insert this library into my ionic project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-native-transitions.

I ran the command to install the plugin:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions
```

I then inserted the dependency into my code, but it didn't work and reading this issue https://github.com/shprink/ionic-native-transitions/issues/29 I found out I needed to insert the script into my project so...

I have an index.html file located in:

```
frontend/www/index.html.
```

I have a js file I need located in:

```
frontend/node_modules/ionic-native-transitions/dist/ionic-native-transitions.js
```

I need to use this javascript file inside of my index.html file so I include it into my header:

```
<script src="../node_modules/ionic-native-transitions/dist/ionic-native-transitions.js"></script>
```

Inside of my IDE it says the path is valid and I can go to the declaration of this file inside of my IDE.

When I run the application, I get the following output in my console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND `file:///android_asset/node_modules/ionic-native-transitions/dist/ionic-native-transitions.js`
```

I am unsure why this is happening. How could I insert this script into my code then?

[image]

Comment: please post a snapshot of project folder structure

Comment: @user2181397 please see updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a problem with the plugin. I followed this tutorial now and I got it working: http://www.gajotres.net/handling-native-view-animations-with-ionic-framework/. There is no requirement to load any scripts.